# Attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to broadcast a hashmap in Python that I would like to use for lookups on worker nodes.

```
class datatransform:

   # Constructor

    def __init__(self, lookupFileName, dataFileName):
        self.lookupFileName = lookupFileName
        self.dataFileName = dataFileName
        self.hamp = {}
        self.broadcastVar = None;

    # Read lookup file from the filesystem and create a local hashmap
    # first and then create a broadcast variable.

    def create_dictionary(self):
        lookup_read = sc.textFile(self.lookupFileName)
        self.lookup_parsed = (lookup_read
            .map(lambda line: [line.split('\t')[0], line.split('\t')[1]]))
        self.broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(self.lookup_parsed)

    # This function will map the given id to a new index using the broadcasted hashmap.

    def featurize(self) :
        data_projected = sqlContext.sql("SELECT uid, prod_id FROM userprods ")
        data = data_projected.map(lambda p: [p.uid, p.prod_id])
        bcastmap = self.broadcastVar
        data_featurized = (data_projected
            .map(lambda p: [p.uid, bcastmap.value[p.prod_id]]))

datatransform = datatransform ('/path/to/lookupfile', '/path/to/datafile')

datatransform.create_dictionary()

datatransform.read_data()
```

I get the following error message:

> Error message: 
>   It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an "
>   Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to broadcast a dictionary you should collect first. It means that `create_dictionary` should look more or less like this

```
def create_dictionary(self):
    lookup_read = sc.textFile(self.lookupFileName)
    lookup_parsed = (lookup_read
        .map(lambda line: [line.split('\t')[0], line.split('\t')[1]]))
    self.broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(lookup_parsed.collectAsMap())
```